# Passing data back to Django view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Inside of a table in my template I have the following which works great:

```
<tbody>
{% for item in items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.status }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.start_time }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.end_time }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to add a form that posts the `items` to a view.  I've tried this:

```
<form align="center" action="{% url 'app:doit' %}" method="post" ><b></b>
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="items" value="{{ items}}" />
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export" >
</form>
```

but that doesn't work as I expected it would. The data comes into the view as a sequence of characters, something like this, ",..." How do I pass `{{items}}` back to a view so I can process the items as python objects?

The export method in my view contains this:

```
if 'items' in request.POST:
    my_items = request.POST['items']
```

Comment: If it's only exporting and not modifying, you can use a list of ids separated by commas. Keep in mind that users can modify that field, so you may want to consider doing some [Cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signing/) to ensure that the field is not tampered with.

Comment: I'd like to pass the entire collection as is.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to do this. The objects came from the backend in the first place, so why would you want to send them back there?

Comment: User requests some data to display in UI.  Then user decides to export that data to a csv file.  The data presented is the result of a database query and subsequent calculations.  I just prefer not to repeat that effort.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `POST` a `QuerSet` back to a view. HTML form cannot understand a Django `QuerySet`. That would be nice, though!

What you can do is to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) that would generate this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items" value="{% my_items items %}" />
```

to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items" value="1,2,5,7,8" />
```

where these numbers are the `id` of each `item`. You can also use the `name` field if you like, since it's not very secure to expose the `id`s.

Then, once `POST`ed, inside the view I would do:

```
if 'items' in request.POST:
    # my_item_values is a str
    my_item_values = request.POST['items']
    try:
        my_item_values = my_item_values.split(',')
    except TypeError:
        # Handle error of conversion from string to list here
    else: 
        # typecast succedded. Get your items!
        items = Item.objects.filter(id__in=my_item_values)  # This is a QuerySet
        # or this (if you used the names)
        items = Item.objects.filter(name__in=my_item_values)  # This is a QuerySet
```

The custom template tag would look like this:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def my_items(items):
    return ','.join([item.name for item in items])
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never implemented a custom template tag before, so thanks for the link.  Thanks I'll try it.

Comment: It should be noted that this approach with a template tag is preferred only if you're going to be doing this a lot in different templates. It's faster to just do the list comprehension directly in your view and pass it into the context.

Comment: Not sure I follow the last comment.  The data being from view to template works great now.  I just want to be able to pass that data to another view.  I will likely do the same from three different templates.